# JwtModule doesn't add Authorization header

Tags: angular, jwt, angular7, angular2-jwt

On a Angular 7+ project, I tried to use the [@auth0/angular-jwt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt) module to add a Bearer token as Authorization header before sending request to a protected rest api.

I sent a request on the whitelisted URL and got a 401 exception, then I checked the Network (using fiddler) which header was transmited, the Authorization header was not there.

I followed all of the [readme](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt) indication, and even checked If I included only once the HttpClientModule.

**app.module.ts :**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { tokenGetter } from './environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// ... other components

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
    // ... other components
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: ["localhost:8080"]
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**environment.ts :**

```
export function tokenGetter() {
    return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}
```

Comment: The link you provided for the readme is for an AngularJS application, not Angular. Is this the correct link? Also, Angular provides a http service with interceptors, in these interceptors you can attach your bearer token. One last thing, does your localStorage actually have an item called `access_token` ?

Comment: Oops, I edit the link ! The module should provide the HttpInterceptor

Comment: Ok, either way, where do you call `localStorage.setItem` ?

Comment: On a AuthService, I checked on console the token is set, actually the getter function  is used

Comment: why do you need a library ? whats wrong with adding it via a simple interceptor?

Comment: Nothing, just wan't it to be secure and maintained. And now it's just frustrating that it doesn't work so I want to find out why !

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, the demo for angular atm does not save the JWT token data in local storage, it seems that auth0 is pushing away from the practice of storing jwt data in the browser's local_storage, since it could be vulnerable to XSS attacks, thus they are suggesting to use cookies.... Yes cookies omg! That's a contradiction since in the past they stated that cookies were not a good practice to use with api calls. I'm using angular 7 + net core 2.2 for web api.

Comment: @Luther nothing wrong with cookies. Its a protection against XSS(from which there is always a risk) and sending only over https by configuring the cookie correctly. Furthermore no interceptor needed and this possible issue that the asker of this question is encountering, cookies are sent on every request by the browser. As protection goes cookies are way more secure. But like everything there are always drawbacks

Comment: @Merv sure, I'm not stating that cookies are bad, I'm just reporting what auth0's guideline was in the past. Still, while building apps for mobile devices (android) but not web apps, dealing with tokens is easier that cookies, that said, you can still use cookies. No code is 100% safe.

Answer (score 3):

I am on Angular 9 and this code snippet worked for JwtModule in the app.module.ts file. It's no longer whitelistedomains and blacklisteddomains anymore it's allowedDomains and disallowedRoutes in the latest version now.  Hope this helps the official doc is here
https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt

```
    JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return localStorage.getItem('token');
    },
    allowedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
    disallowedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
  }
})
```

]

You can also do export function as well for the tokenGetter, but I just wanted to show how it would work in one code snippet. Happy coding!

**package.json:**

```
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1",
```

**app.module.ts import code:**

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
```

**Complete imports code:**

```
  imports: [
BrowserModule,
HttpClientModule,
FormsModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
NgxGalleryModule,
TabsModule.forRoot(),
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return localStorage.getItem('token');
    },
    allowedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
    disallowedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
  }
})
```

],

[techjunkieblog](https://www.techjunkieblog.com)

Comment: Make sure it's in the imports section of the app.module.ts section I put it at the end also make sure HttpClientModule  has been imported before using the jwt library.  If you get the error that allowedDomains is not defined then you might be using an earlier version and have to use whitelistedDomains instead.  Look in your package.json file mine is    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.0.1", with Angular 9